# Cannot return value from function

Tags: php, function, return

I have a PHP function:

```php
function unserialize_recursive($data, $i = 0) {

    $unserialized = unserialize($data);

    if ($unserialized) {
        $i++;
    }

    if (!is_string($unserialized) || unserialize($unserialized) === FALSE) {
        /* placeholder - see explanation below */
        return array($i, $unserialized);
    } elseif (unserialize($unserialized) !== FALSE) {
        unserialize_recursive($unserialized, $i);
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I call this function with:

```php
$data = unserialize_recursive($serialized_string);
var_dump($data);
```

But the output of `var_dump($data)` is `bool(false)`.

However, if I add `var_dump($unserialized)` in the position of the text `/* placeholder - see explanation below */`, I get the expected output.

So why can I not return that variable (`$unserialized`)? If I use `gettype()` on it at that point in the function, it returns `array`.

I'm using Netbeans and all the syntax highlighting indicates the code is properly formed with no typos.  I'm baffled. Have I missed something really obvious?

Comment: Why are you using `FALSE` instead of `false`?

Comment: I think you forgot a return. You might also need to pass in your $i parameter by reference.

Comment: @Dai: While that question is pretty irrelevant and I have my doubts you're actually interested, the answer is that I use the uppercase version for readability reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **return** in front of

> unserialize_recursive($unserialized, $i);

So it should be like this

> **return** unserialize_recursive($unserialized, $i);

Without return function would run itself but then leave if condition and execute return FALSE. By placing return in front you end the current function and start another one.

Comment: Thanks - the line about ending the function and starting another one is the part that made most sense to me, though I'm actually still confused about why it doesn't work the way I first wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you forgot a return:

```
function unserialize_recursive($data, $i = 0) {

$unserialized = unserialize($data);

if ($unserialized) {
    $i++;
}

if (!is_string($unserialized) || unserialize($unserialized) === FALSE) {
    /* placeholder - see explanation below */
    return array($i, $unserialized);
} elseif (unserialize($unserialized) !== FALSE) {
    return unserialize_recursive($unserialized, $i);
}
return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use recursion in your function.

So your var_dump($unserialized) is called from a recursed invocation, but main invocation returns false.

You probably need to change "unserialize_recursive($unserialized, $i);" to

```
return unserialize_recursive($unserialized, $i);
```